# What happens to a socket on suspend/resume in windows

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, c#-4.0

I have a c# .net4 application that listens on a socket using BeginReceiveFrom and EndRecieveFrom.  All works as expected until I put the machine to sleep and then resume.

At that point EndReceieveFrom executes and throws an exception (Cannot access a disposed object). It appears that the socket is disposed when the machine is suspended but I'm not sure how to handle this.

Do I presume that all sockets have been disposed and recreate them all from scratch? I'm having problems tracking down the exact issue as remote debugging also breaks on suspend/resume.

Comment: I expect that the system throws some events which you could try to handle your reconnection problem.

Comment: This is networking code - you need to be able to handle "connection dropped for any reason" anyway (i.e. implement some sort of auto-reconnect) - so suspend/resume should not be much of special case... Or I'm missing something?

Comment: It's a multicast listener so doesn't have a remote endpoint as such.I'm trying to understand what is happening during the suspend so I can best address the issue.

Answer (score 3):

What happens during suspend/resume very much depends on your hardware and networking setup. If your network card is not disabled during suspend, and the suspend is brief, open connections will survive suspend/resume without any problem (open TCP connections can time out on the other end of course).

However, if your network adapter is disabled during the sleep, or it is a USB adapter that gets disabled because it is connected to a disabled hub, or your computer gets a new IP address from DHCP, or your wireless adapter gets reconnected to a different access point, etc., then all current connections are going to be dropped, listening sockets wil no longer be valid, etc.

This is **not** specific to sleep/resume. Network interfaces can come up and go down at any time, and your code must handle it. You can easily simulate this with a USB network adapter, e.g. yank it out of your computer and your code must handle it.

Comment: Whatever is happening is definitely specific to sleep/resume.My code will happily handle network interfaces (Wireless/Wired etc..)coming up and down and also IP changes.What I'm seeing is only happening after I resume.The tricky part is that the program runs fine if I perform the test whilst it's running though VS in debug mode but standalone will ALWAYS fail after resume.By the time I can fire up a command prompt the socket is shown to be present.To get around it I've had to stop and start the socket when an error is detected with reuse address = 1 as the original socket is still there.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issues with suspend/resume and sockets (under .NET 4 and Windows 8, but I suspect not limited to these).

Specifically, I had a client socket application which only received data. Reading was done via BeginReceive with a call-back. Code in the call-back handled typical failure cases (e.g. remote server closes connection either gracefully or not).

When the client machine went to sleep (and this probably applies to the newer Windows 8 Fast Start mode too which is really just a kind of sleep/hibernate) the server would close the connection after a few seconds. When the client woke up however the async read call-back was not getting called (which I would expect to occur as it should get called when the socket has an error condition/is closed in addition to when there is data). I explicitly added code on a timer to the client to periodically check for this condition and recover, however even here (and using a combination of Poll, Available and Connected to check if the connection was up) the socket on the client side STILL appeared to be connected, so the recovery code never ran. I think if I had tried sending data then I would have received an error, but as I said this was strictly one-way.

The solution I ended up using was to detect the resume from sleep condition and close and re-establish my socket connections when this occurred. There are quite a few ways of detecting resume; in my case I was writing a Windows Service, so I could simply override the ServiceBase.OnPowerEvent method.